# Display TFS queries in Word

Tags: c#, excel, tfs, ms-word, ms-office

I'm a few months into programming, and I have task right now to create a new Ribbon Tab for Word where I can pick a Template and a TFS query to be displayed in that template. It already exists exactly like that in Excel. I have the Tab and a few Buttons, like 'Select Query', but how do I get the TFS Project Collections, and do I create a WinForm as a dialog for picking a project? I'm new to the whole Office thing in Visual Studio.
Isn't there a way to get the code behind the Excel 'Team'-Tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://www.modernrequirements.com/. This is a tool that already does things like this for you.

But if you want to reinvent the weel, then you can check https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/get-started/create-and-debug-office-add-ins-in-visual-studio for information how to create your own plugin. You custom office plugin with connection to the TFS api (see: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/overview) will make you go a long way.